# Passing xml string parameter to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am passing an xml string to stored procedure in SQL Server for inserting 10000 records to my table. In this when I call this stored procedure. Want to check the SQL Server table with that xml string which I am passing, if the record exists I don't want to insert, if it is new record that record alone have to insert.Give some solution. Thanks.

```
  ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_CMSUSER1]
      (@xmlString ntext)
    as
    begin

      DECLARE @idoc INT
      DECLARE @data nvarchar(100)

      EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xmlString

    INSERT INTO dbo.Seg_RecipientsTemp (ContactID,first_name,last_name,company,email,last_updated)
    SELECT ContactID,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    company,
    email,
    last_updated FROM OPENXML(@idoc,

    '/NewDataSet/ContactData', 6)

    WITH

    (ContactID int ,
    first_name nvarchar(50), 
    last_name  nvarchar(50), 
    company    nvarchar(max),
    email nvarchar(100), 
    last_updated datetime 



    )
    end
```

My Xml is:

```
 <NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <ContactID>2</ContactID>
    <last_name>klklk</last_name>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ContactID>4</ContactID>
    <first_name>k</first_name>
    <last_name>kk</last_name>
    <company>k</company>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ContactID>6</ContactID>
    <first_name>naveen</first_name>
    <last_name />
    <company>inno</company>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ContactID>7</ContactID>
    <first_name>sridar</first_name>
    <last_name />
    <company>mahindara</company>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ContactID>1</ContactID>
    <first_name>terst</first_name>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ContactID>2</ContactID>
    <first_name />
    <last_name>ask</last_name>
    <company />
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to **see a sample XML** and get an explanation of what you want to extract from it!

Comment: i want to check if the contactid exists in sql table with xml string,if already exists i dont want insert ,new record only have to insert,,i need If not exists(select * from dbo.Seg_RecipientsTemp where Contact_Id=(in this i need check with xml conatacid)

Comment: Do you want to INSERT the records for `ContactID`'s that don't exist in `dbo.Seg_RecipientsTemp` but exist in XML data? Do you want to UPDATE the data in `dbo.Seg_RecipientsTemp` for `ContactID`'s that do exist in XML data?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Every version since 2005 has supported a proper `xml` data type, and it would be far better to use that if possible

Comment: no I dont want to update existing,i dont do anything with that,if the new record comes i need to insert.i dont want update for existing records

Comment: I am using 2008,i dont know my source table value is NULL now

Answer (score 13):

Define your stored procedure to take a parameter of type **XML** (don't use `ntext` anymore! It's deprecated). And don't use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures - it's a reserved prefix for internal use by Microsoft and causes performance degradation - use something else! (or don't use any prefix at all)

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].InsertCmsUser
      @xmlString XML
 AS
     ......
```

Try this (using the **native** XQuery methods in SQL Server **2005** and newer, instead of the rather messy `OPENXML` interface....):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        ContactID = XTbl.value('(ContactID)[1]', 'int'),
        FirstName = XTbl.value('(first_name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        LastName = XTbl.value('(last_name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        Company = XTbl.value('(company)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
    FROM 
        @input.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table') AS XD(XTbl)
)
INSERT INTO 
    dbo.Seg_RecipientsTemp (ContactID, first_name, last_name, company, last_updated)
    SELECT 
        ContactID,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        Company,
        GETDATE()
    FROM
        CTE
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Seg_RecipientsTemp WHERE ContactID = CTE.ContactID)
```

I didn't find any `email` attribute in your XML - not sure where you want to get that from ....

**Update:** ok, so you seem to also have `<last_updated>` elements in your **real** XML ....

```
<last_updated>2012-09-12T22:59:10.813+05:30</last_updated>
```

This looks like a `DATETIMEOFFSET` to me - since it has the `+05:30` time zone addition.

In that case, use this code instead:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        ContactID = XTbl.value('(ContactID)[1]', 'int'),
        FirstName = XTbl.value('(first_name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        LastName = XTbl.value('(last_name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        Company = XTbl.value('(company)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
            LastUpdated = XTbl.value('(last_updated)[1]', 'datetimeoffset')
    FROM 
        @input.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table') AS XD(XTbl)
)
INSERT INTO 
    dbo.Seg_RecipientsTemp (ContactID, first_name, last_name, company, last_updated)
    SELECT 
        ContactID,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        Company,
        LastUpdated
    FROM
        CTE
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Seg_RecipientsTemp WHERE ContactID = CTE.ContactID)
```

Comment: Thanx for your response.Sorry email id there i didnot added in xml for testing purpose,i got an error i got another problem Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string for lastupdated field,,in xml i get below tag <last_updated>2012-09-12T22:59:10.813+05:30</last_updated> ..please give some solution

Comment: @Kamalakannan.M: it would have been nice to see such a `<last_updated>` tag in the sample you posted! See my updated response

Comment: XML parsing: line 76442, character 53, illegal xml character

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to comment yet, but hoping to help even though this isn't a real answer. 
This page offers a great detailed explanation:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/the-xml-methods-in-sql-server/
(not affiliated)

> The nodes() method The nodes() method can be a bit more slippery to
>   understand than the other XML methods. To begin with, rather than
>   returning XML or scalar values, ***the nodes() method returns what is
>   essentially a table that includes one column***. That means you should
>   use the method only in those parts of a statement that can handle
>   rowset views, such as the FROM clause. It also means that, when you
>   call the nodes() method, you must assign a table alias and column
>   alias to the rowset view returned by the method, as shown in the
>   following syntax:
>
> DbObject.nodes('XQuery') AS TableAlias(ColumnAlias)